# Vault - How to list folders from a specific path on a kv v2 secret engine using HVAC?

Tags: python, hashicorp-vault

I'm trying to retrieve all the folders from a specific path in my Vault. In order to do this, I'm using the hvac Vault API client for Python.

I can easily list the folders from a kv v1 secret engine using the following command:

```
import hvac

client = hvac.Client(url=vault_host)    
list_folders = client.list('my/path/')
```

However, this does not work with kv v2 secret engines. I tried to look up [the documentation](https://hvac.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#read-and-write-to-secrets-engines), but it looks that it is only possible to retrieve a list of secrets. For example, this won't work unless a secret is stored in the path:

```
list_folders = client.secrets.kv.read_secret_version(path='my/path/')
```

Do you have any idea how I could manage to get the list of my folders on a kv v2 secret engine?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking up the documentation, it appears the correct method to use is [`list_secrets`](https://hvac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/secrets_engines/kv_v2.html#list-secrets). So, in order to get the folders using a specific path, I used the following code:

```
list_response = client.secrets.kv.v2.list_secrets(
    path='my/path/'
)
list_folders = list_response['data']['keys']
print(list_folders)
```

This outputs a list with the name of the folders available:

```
['dev/', 'prod/']
```

Also, be careful if you're working with a dev-mode server of your Vault, as it defaults the path to `secret/`. More info can be found in the [Vault documentation](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/kv/kv-v2.html#setup).